# Remove tags from XML in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing, tags

Can PowerShell script remove all tags and texts in XML file and keep only binary data ? Tags and texts in tags block me to decript binary code.

```
<message id="3" date="2010">
<text>4+Cj4+CmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb...</text></message>
```

Need remove all and keep clear binary code and re-saved file.

```
4+Cj4+CmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb...
```

Is even possible do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell loves XML. If you just import your data to a a variable cast as XML, you don't have to do regex stuff. You can use `Get-Content` or just copy/paste like this:

```
[xml]$MyData = '<message id="3" date="2010"><text>4+Cj4+CmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb...</text></message>'
$MyData.message.text
```